# Anti-forgery error when opening Identity Server

Tags: identity-server

I am running Sitecore XP 9.2 and installed the Identity Server (IS) without SSL.

Opening (e.g.) http://identity/.well-known/openid-configuration and retrieving tokens works fine. But I get an error while opening the IS homepage, e.g. http://identity.

The full error from the IS log is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery system has the configuration value AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Always, but the current request is not an SSL request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.CheckSSLConfig(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.AntiforgeryExtensions.GetHtml(IAntiforgery antiforgery, HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I ran the IS before without SSL with no problems, so I am a bit puzzled.

Any clues on what setting I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is stating that your `AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy` is set to `Always`.  This means, that for the cookie to be provided to the client, the request has to start on HTTPS and stay on HTTPS.  However, you should be able override the `CookieAuthentication` processor in the `<owin.initialize>` pipeline to allow the authentication cookie to be shared across HTTP requests and not just HTTPS requests.  See the Microsoft documentation for further information on [CookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieSecure Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt152267%28v%3dvs.113%29) and the [CookieSecureOption Enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn284294%28v%3dvs.113%29).

In the meantime, below is a custom processor you can use to set the `CookieSecureOption` to `Never` so that the cookie will be shared on HTTP and HTTPS regardless of where the request started.

```cs
public class CustomCookieAuthentication : Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.Initialize.CookieAuthentication
{
    public CustomCookieAuthentication(DefaultCookieAuthenticationOptions cookieAuthenticationOptions, BaseSettings settings)
        : base(cookieAuthenticationOptions, settings)
    {
    }

    public override void Process(InitializeArgs args)
    {
        this.CookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never;
        base.Process(args);
    }
}
```

You can then patch in your custom processor to the pipeline.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
               xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/"
               xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <pipelines>
      <owin.initialize>
        <processor name="CookieAuthentication">
            <patch:attribute name="type">__Namespace__.CustomCookieAuthentication, __DLL__</patch:attribute>
        </processor>
      </owin.initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

A couple of notes:

- The `CookieSecureOption.Never` is fine for local development, but you should consider `Always` or at least `SameAsRequest` for production servers.
- Remember to change out the `__Namespace__` and `__DLL__` sections of that config to match your setup.
- Also, I do not have the ability to test this code currently, so keep a keen eye out when trying it out.

Comment: Please note that this is necessary since IS v9.1.1.